# Multiple deployment in elastic beanstalk environment within same application using travis

Tags: amazon-s3, travis-ci, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

How do I deploy my java application in multiple environment within same application in elastic beanstalk.

Comment: For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You could also read the [Deploying Applications to AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environments](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.deploy-existing-version.html) documentation.